# Is it possible two combine two linear gradient in css over single div

Tags: css, background, linear-gradients

I want to make the following using css

[See Resultant Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VaMQ.png)

Thus far I have made the horizontal lines using repeating-linear-gradient

```css
.pattern1{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, white, white 40px, black 3px, black 43px)
}
```

```html
<div class='pattern1'/>
```

But i need to add left vertical line of 30px within same div using css.

Here is the fiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

```css
.pattern1{
  height: 252px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) left/30px 100% no-repeat,
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0 40px, black 0 42px)
}
```

```html
<div class='pattern1'></div>
```

OR like below:

```css
.pattern1{
  height: 252px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, red 30px, transparent 0),
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0 40px, black 0 42px)
}
```

```html
<div class='pattern1'></div>
```

Comment: Why the horizontal lines are of different sizes?

Comment: @Hassan they are not, all of them are 2px and we repeat this

Comment: @Hassan I run the code and I don't see any difference. Make sure you don't have any zomm activated in your code or increase the 42px to 43px